# Not able to tell if Hystrix Circuit is FORCED Open with micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, hystrix, micrometer

When setting `hystrix.command.HystrixCommandKey.circuitBreaker.forceOpen` to true, the metric from micrometer, `hystrix.circuit.breaker.open` does not pick up the forced open circuit breaker and remain as 0.

In addition, there doesn't seem to be any information regarding the FORCED open state.

The number of short-circuited events (hystrix.execution.total{event="short_circuited"}) increases but `hystrix.circuit.breaker.open` still remain 0.

Is there a way that I can get the **forced open** hystrix circuit state metric for monitoring?